# What part of speech is "almost" when applied to an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, modifiers

If I say that "the box is almost flat" what part of speech is "almost"?

I can't say "the box is almost", so it does not appear to be an adjective itself.  It seems to be a word that modifies the adjective "flat".

I note that the online definitions say it is an adjective and and adverb, neither of which I really understand the reasoning for.  [One example of online definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/almost)

Comment: What did the dictionary suggest? And why didn't you believe it? :-)

Comment: Your next question might be <What part of speech is 'quite' in the sentence 'the box is not quite flat'> Which would be an interesting question. 'Almost' clearly modifies 'is'. It almost is, but not quite. But 'quite' in 'not quite'; is perhaps a little more tricky. I have up-voted your down-vote.

Comment: @tchrist  Of course I should have mentioned, though it's kind of a given, that I looked it up and didn't understand the answer.   I got "it is an adjective and an adverb"  [one example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/almost).   Neither of these made sense to me, hence the question.   Now I have learned about "adjective of degree" thanks to the very helpful answer.  Aren't the people who provide such answers helpfully here wonderful eh?

Comment: @GreenAsJade I don’t understand why you don’t think adverb makes sense – adverbs modify verbs and adjectives, and since _almost_ modifies _flat_, adverb would be the obvious choice.

Comment: I didn't know that adverbs are things that modify adjectives!

Comment: @NigelJ _Almost_ can be said to modify _is_, but it seems more economical to say that it modifies _flat_. Otherwise what would you do about “An almost flat box stood on the table”? You can’t very well say that _almost_ modifies _stood_ there, both because you’d have to extract it from in between the determiner and the adjective, and also because it didn’t almost stand on the table – it **did** stand on the table. Makes most sense to analyse the two in the same way to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So the adverb 'almost' or 'quite' modifies the adjective 'flat'.

Comment: @NigelJ I would say so, yes, in this instance. It becomes clearer, I think, if you use _not quite_ and a determiner, because then you can move things around and see what modifies what when (_>_ meaning ‘modifies’ here): **It’s a not quite flat box** : (_not_ > _quite_) > _flat_. **It’s not a quite flat box** : _not_ > _is_, _quite_ > _flat_. **It’s not quite a flat box** : (_not_ > _quite_) > _is_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It can be almost a box, and it can almost be a box — but somehow having it be an almost box feels different to me, almost. I'm thinking only one of those is close to being an adjective, and even that one still resists being used predicatively. I don't think you can say that you know that your almost box is one of those kinds of boxes simply because all your boxes are almost. They aren't almost ones.

Comment: Classically, an adverb of degree. For those who've lost the adverb dustbin, a secondary modifier (subclass adjectival).

Comment: Um - I posted the research that I'd done (online dictionaries) and why I found this still to be a question.  Further, the subsequent discussion shows that it is not a well understood topic, and that the actual answer is not contained in a typical dictionary.   Therefore, I object to this being closed.  (even though I have the answer I needed now, so this objection is about fair procedure, not outcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "Almost" is an **adverb**. ([source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/almost))

More specifically, it is an **[adverb of degree](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-degree/)**.